# how to write an "or" operation while translating Grammar to regex

Tags: regex, formal-languages

I want to translate following grammar to regex

```
A -> bcA | dD |aB
B -> aB |a
D -> dD |d
```

So here string will end either in a's or d's

Regular expression will start with (bc)+

but can anyone explain how can write d+/a+ in regular expression for languages?

Comment: A modular regex with PCRE: https://regex101.com/r/gL9tC6/1 but I guess this isn't what you were asked to do...

Comment: Yeah, this is not exactly what i am looking for. Am looking for (bc)+a+d+            ...but there should be an or expression between a+ and d+

Comment: Isn't it just (bc)*(aa+|dd+)? (I note that there should be at least 2 a's or 2 d's and the (bc) is optional) like this: https://regex101.com/r/gL9tC6/2

Comment: yeah true there would be aa+ or dd+, am not sure about using '|' while translating grammar to regex

Comment: `|` is part of formal regular expression. You can use it as such, it is called "[alternation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_definition)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the regex dialect you're using.

In general, a `|` within a `()` grouping creates an 'or', for example:

```
th(er|os)e
```

... matches 'there' or 'those'.

But check the documentation for your dialect, to check whether brackets have to be escaped, whether '|' is supported, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach too:

```
(bc)*(d{2,}|a{2,})
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]